# How to use custom-bib to customize in text citation into format Author, year

Tags: natbib, custom-bib

As the title says, I have to use custom-bib package to change the format of the references in the reference page, therefore I cannot use the natbib package

```
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
```

The outcome I would like to have is

> Some text (Author, 2020)

But the best I could get with the custom-bib is

> Some text (Author (2020))

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The [natbib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) and [custom-bib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib) packages were written by the same person, *viz.*, Patrick Daly. The claim that one can't use a bibliography style created by the `custom-bib` package together with the `natbib` citation management package is *false*.

Comment: Please show the code that you use to generate the two citation call-outs.

Comment: As Mico says, usually `custom-bib` styles can be used together with `natbib`. You can even explicitly select full `natbib` compatibility of the citation commands. So you should be able to load `natbib` and use its `\citep` and `\citet` commands instead of plain old `\cite`. If you tried that and it does not work for you, please show us a small example document that reproduces the issue (you will have to share your custom `.bst` file, which is likely too large to be included here, so please make it available via a text-sharing website such as https://pastebin.com/).